# How to use map on two arrays of the same length and compare them

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

So what i'm wondering is how do i give the first character of the splitted string an id of 0, and push a corresponding id into Uids[]. I'm trying to make a speed typing game, and i need to give the first character an id of 0, and so on, so that i can check user input against my string, one by one.

```js
let sitatRandom = sitat_array[Math.floor(Math.random() * sitat_array.length)];

// Zip higher order function
const zip = (a, b) => a.map((k, i) => [k, b[i]]);

var sitat_splitted = sitatRandom.split();
var uids = [];
for (let i = 0; i < sitat_splitted.length; i++) {
  const id = 'id' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(2);
  uids.push(id);
}
  const uid_splitted = zip(sitat_splitted, uids);

  function fyllSitat() {
   const sitat_div = document.getElementById('sitat');

   for (let i = 0; i < uid_splitted.length; i++) {
   var new_span = document.createElement('span');
   new_span.setAttribute('id', uid_splitted[i][1]);
   new_span.innerText = `${uid_splitted[i][0]}`;

   sitat_div.appendChild(new_span);
}
  }
```